# Why is there a Red Cross against my User Group in Team Explorer > Team Members?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Recently our Development user group (Windows) has started showing with a Red Cross in Team Explorer and we cannot expand it anymore.

I have tried removing and re-adding the group but to no avail.

Does anyone know why it would display like this?

We are using TFS 2010 with VS2010 SP1 and August's Power Toys.!

[image: Team Explorer]

BTW, "Technical Testing Team" is another Windows Domain User Group, just like Development and that works OK.

Comment: How could this be considered off-topic?

Comment: I can see that it's on the borderline between SO and ServerFault - but I personally think it's relevant enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the General tab of the VS Output windows there is a message:

> Skipping loading group Development into Team Members because it has 102 members.

Looks like VS has a limit on here.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the red crosses on particular services are caused either by that service being unavailable or by permissions issues...

Are you still able to perform actions that require admin permissions? Does this apply to a single project or all?

How are you defining your developers? A windows domain group? If so, is the TFS server able to see the DC?

I'd suggest you try installing [Team Explorer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=329) on the TFS server and running it when logged on as yourself - see if you have the same problem. If not, it may be network or firewall problems between your dev machine and the server. At least it would narrow the problem down.

**Edit 1:**

Do reports work properly? (Specifically, do the graphs show up in reports)?

What auth are you using? Kerberos?

What account is TFS running as? What permissions (if any) does that account have on the network?

Can you see the security information you'd expect in the TFS_Configuration database? (Try tbl_SecurityAccessControlEntry) [Usual "Change nothing, do it at your own risk" disclaimer]

**Edit 2:**

As per the install docs, the TFS service should be running under its own account (IIRC they suggest `Domain\TFS.Service`). Check the permissions on the windows services on the TFS Server and see who they're running as. Makes sure the permissions for that user are correct as per the [installation instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337)

NTLM can cause problems as it doesn't allow credentials to be delegated/relayed the way Kerberos does (and has some picky setup requirements) - but that's obviously not why it's broken all of a sudden (and that usually manifests as graphs not displaying in reports).

WRT: the SecurityAccessControlEntry table, I was more interested in making sure there were entries and that it could be read properly than the contents.

I assume you've tried deleting/recreating groups - If not, give it a shot (deleting the domain group may be an issue with other services but try using a different (new) group and removing the old one from TFS entirely)

I have to admit I'm running out of ideas after that. If it were me, I'd try a clean install on a new server/VM and either point the new install at the old data store [multiple server setup] or export/import projects [single server setup].

For Multiple server setups, this would determine if it's a TFS installation issue/data corruption. For single-server, there's a good chance this would just clean up the problem. You could, of course, also ex/import on multi-server too if it does turn out to be a data thing.

You may want to hang on to see if someone has a less drastic solution.

Comment: Yes, I can perform admin operations and it is all probject. Developers is a Windows Domain User Group (so is "Technical Testing Team" which is working). I have tried Team Explorer on the server logged on as me, and it's the same problem. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Graphs work OK, Authentication is NTLM. What do you mean by TFS? I doubt it is the account it is running as, as it can see the users of "Teacnical Testing Team". The tbl_SecurityAccessControlEntry table looks OK, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: @DaveShaw I've added Edit 2 with some final ideas. Hope something in there helps.

Comment: We are using a TFSService account. I don't think it's related the account(s) TFS is using because the other domain user group is visible. It's a single server setup at the moment. I'll try some stuff on our play server, and see what that does. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Dave is the issue also present on a different installation of TFS (Your "play" server) ?

Comment: My "Play" server has been "borrowed". When I get some time I will install a VM and see what that's like. Although I noticed today, this problem is present on all Projects in the Collection.